# How to render OBJ or FBX in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, fbx

I have couple of 3D objects in .obj and .fbx format with included mtl and texture files. I would like to know which is the best library to render those in Android. All I want to achieve is to display the 3D object inside activity, and add touch gestures (drag and pinch zoom).

Comment: well that's amusing. Anyways for now trying with Rajawali but unable to load mtl file which is associated with obj.

Comment: There's numerous libraries for 3D rendering on Android. LibGdx is an easy one to use and loads both .obj and .fbx.

Comment: @WLGfx let me try that. I didn't got it in any google search. Hope it works. Will update soon :)

Comment: The link for LibGDX: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: Yeah I already got and able to create an Android project but getting some weird error while loading the obj file. Trying to replicate the same from https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-models-using-libgdx/

Comment: I am getting this error : com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=-235648 out of bounds (limit=1495736)

Comment: Usually a limit on a single mesh is 64k vertices, so you will need to chop that down. Any other problems with the .obj files are also fixed when using fbxconv that you get with LibGdx. If in your modelling app you can split the meshes up then that will be fine. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So it has to be done from Blender for example right? Even Rajawali library was showing the same kinda error. Kinda new to this 3D thing so got confused 

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple meshes in an object, just keep each mesh below 64k vertices. Blender might even split them for you, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying both Rajawali and libGDX I can say Rajawali is a bit easier to implement if the intention is not game development. Here is the link to Rajawali library : [GitHub Link](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/)

Their support is really good and devs reply quite quickly and resolve issues when reported at GitHub.