# how to render and display a 3d object on the screen in java or kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a question that is consuming a lot of time and effort. I am doing a kotlin project and I need to execute and render on the screen 3D objects with movement (.fbx, .dae, .obj), but the animation size (100dp x 100dp) must be specific. Imagine it like an image or an imageview in the activity/fragment that will display a 3D object with movement. I've done a lot of research but I'm kind of stuck. Could you give me any recommendations or help me with this in any way?

Comment: Doing this from scratch is a big task. You would need to learn OpenGL, how to work with native memory (JNI), how to write shaders (GLSL), etc. I recommend using an existing library like libGDX. libGDX is intended for games. There might be smaller libraries available to do just the model rendering.

Comment: Have you seen: [How to render OBJ or FBX in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46251162/295004)

Comment: Oh thanks, i already used it from a game 2D but never in 3D